After reinstalling the gdm3 package and ubuntu-desktop, the system cannot start
I was recently trying to fix a headphone driver issue and followed the instructions in this answer on askubuntu. By the way, I have the latest version of ubuntu, installed it a little over a month ago, 24.04 LTS, updated regularly. First, I uninstalled and reinstalled the ALSA packages. Then I reinstalled the gdm3 and ubuntu desktop packages (or deleted them, I don’t remember, that’s the point). And after the next start of the PC, the following happens: I turn on the PC, select ubuntu, and I am thrown into a black screen where I need to enter the admin login and password,this message this message is displayed and after a split second it disappears and again they ask for the admin login and password.

What should I do? How to recover data? Is it possible to restore the system to the position it was in before this incident?

As I understand, most likely the problem is that I uninstalled ubuntu-desktop, but what should I do now, can I somehow reinstall it via recovery?

Yes you can run sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop or Sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop-minimal after you log in.

how do I get to the terminal? after I enter my username and password, it asks me to do it again

https://support.starlabs.systems/kb/guides/using-recovery-mode after choosing the recovery mode you will get a page with choices first choose  network and then root

Couldn't you just type in the first window?

I can't enter in the first window, because after entering the password, it requires me to enter it again and so on endlessly. And through recovery I can't enter root because I don't know the root password and the password for my user doesn't match it

h ok, you may need this but firstrun the others I suggested, then if you need this https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password
